# How to activate the planning with obstacles after publishing the planning scene moveit message

Tags: moveit, motion-planning

I'm following the [tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html) of MoveIt to add obstacles to the scene.

Everything goes well and I can see obstacles in Rviz. However, the planned path seems to ignore the presence of obstacles and go through them.

Here is the code snippet that is used to add obstacles:

```
moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene;
planning_scene.world.collision_objects.push_back(attached_object.object);
planning_scene.is_diff = true;
planning_scene_diff_publisher.publish(planning_scene);
```

I follow [this tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/motion_planning_api/motion_planning_api_tutorial.html) to load the `OMPL` plugin.

Actually, I know this problem could be solved with the `move group interface`, but its member function `setGoalOrientationTolerance` can't set orientation tolerance for different directions. So I refer to [this procedure](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/motion_planning_api/motion_planning_api_tutorial.html) to set the pose goal.

Or if there is any way to utilize the `move group interface` to set a pose goal with different tolerances for different axes, I can skip the above hassle.

Help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution, feel free to comment if there is a better way! Note that the code just lists the procedure, not out-of-the-box.

```
  planning_interface::MotionPlanRequest req;
  planning_interface::MotionPlanResponse res;

  geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;

  std::vector<double> tolerance_position;
  std::vector<double> tolerance_angle;

  moveit_msgs::Constraints pose_goal = kinematic_constraints::constructGoalConstraints("end-effector", pose, tolerance_position, tolerance_angle);

  req.group_name = PLANNING_GROUP;
  req.goal_constraints.push_back(pose_goal);

  // set start state
  start_state.setJointGroupPositions(joint_model_group, start_joint_values);

  moveit_msgs::RobotState start_msgs;
  moveit::core::robotStateToRobotStateMsg(start_state, start_msgs);

  req.start_state = start_msgs;

  moveit_msgs::MoveGroupGoal move_group_goal;
  move_group_goal.request = req;
  move_group_goal.planning_options.plan_only = true;
  move_group_goal.planning_options.look_around = false;
  move_group_goal.planning_options.replan = false;
  move_group_goal.planning_options.planning_scene_diff.is_diff = true;
  move_group_goal.planning_options.planning_scene_diff.robot_state.is_diff = true;

  actionlib::SimpleActionClient<moveit_msgs::MoveGroupAction>&
      move_action_client_custom = move_group_interface.getMoveGroupClient();

  move_action_client_custom.sendGoal(move_group_goal);

  if (!move_action_client_custom.waitForResult()) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("MoveGroup action returned early");
  }
  if (move_action_client_custom.getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED) {
    ROS_INFO_STREAM("MoveGroup has finished the plan successfully and costed "
                    << move_action_client_custom.getResult()->planning_time << " seconds");
  } else {
    ROS_WARN_STREAM("Fail: " << move_action_client_custom.getState().toString()
                             << ": "
                             << move_action_client_custom.getState().getText());
  }
```